Растянуть кнопки по ширине
Вот HTML
<div class="inlines_pills">
    <a href="#" class="transparent_pill">Delete</a>
    <a href="#" class="transparent_pill">Edit</a>
    <a href="#" class="transparent_pill">Cancel Edit</a>
</div>

<div class="inlines_pills">
    <a href="#" class="transparent_pill">Edit</a>
    <a href="#" class="transparent_pill">Delete</a>
</div>

Вот CSS
.inlines_pills {
 display: flex;
}

Вот макеты


Как сверстать так как не макете?

@像插頭一樣愚蠢 мне кажется тут речь про flex-grow: 1

Пример


.inlines_pills {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.transparent_pill {  
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
<div class="inlines_pills">
    <a href="#" class="transparent_pill">Delete</a>
    <a href="#" class="transparent_pill">Edit</a>
    <a href="#" class="transparent_pill">Cancel Edit</a>
</div>

<div class="inlines_pills">
    <a href="#" class="transparent_pill">Edit</a>
    <a href="#" class="transparent_pill">Delete</a>
</div>



